# Getting TOKEN NOT FOUND each time on the Bluesnap Payment Gateway with merchant account

Tags: payment, bluesnap

I am trying to do the payment with Hosted Payment Fields of bluesnap but every time it gives me token not found,

Below are the steps which I am doing...

1. Created the payment-fields-tokens
   Called the https://sandbox.bluesnap.com/services/2/payment-fields-tokens with Auth details, and it gives me pfToken in the Location header.
   See screenshot : https://www.screencast.com/t/R9gaUTbmT8
2. Put the token which got from the /payment-feilds-tokens api to the "Try it!" section on the https://developers.bluesnap.com/#section-1-token
   and the clicked on the "Great. Continue to Step 2!" button for next step.
3. Put the Card information as per given inthe "Try it!" section on the left and clicked on the "Pay Now" button. Card data was successfully added to Bluesnap and Got the alert of "Continue on the Step 3!"
4. Copied the json which got on the Step 3 ( Charge  & Vault )and put it to the "Try It Out" box on the https://developers.bluesnap.com/v8976-JSON/docs/auth-capture#api-explorer page.
   https://www.screencast.com/t/o7qZALUkr2yJ
5. Getting error of token not found.
   see screenshot : https://www.screencast.com/t/gwoWs1cndOM

   It's would be much appreciated if help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating the token using your own API credentials in step 1, but then trying to use it on the bluesnap documentation's "try it now" section (step 4) which is most definitely connected to a different account. That's why it can't find your token under this different account.

Comment: you are absolutely correct. that was my mistake which I didn't notice.